# AVI subtype playback issues

Tags: codec, avi

I have two AVI videos. one will play in an application i am using and the other will not.
looking at them in Media Player Classic properties, they have exactly the same specifications
Codec : DVSD
 
Named: DVC/DV
but looking at them in GSpot, I finally found a difference.
the working file uses OpenDML AVI 2.0
whereas the file that will not open uses AVI 1.0
I need to convert one to the other, but i cant find a way to convert from one codec to a different version of the same codec, muchless how to find different editions of the same codec.
If anyone has an idea of how to fix this or what the other differences may be, please let me know. 
The application I am trying to open these with only functions on Windows XP if that is any indication of what the problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the option "save as old avi format" in VirtualDub solves this problem.
http://www.virtualdub.org/download.html